# Backup of answers?

Tags: feature-request

A few months ago, the [question](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/is-poker-a-site-we-should-keep-around) came whether to shut down Poker.SE or not. While this question is not about that, I think it's going to happen, because Poker.SE is not doing very well (maybe the world is just not ready for poker in Q&A StackExchange style).

I've never witnessed a SE beta site go down before, but I suspect that it just.. vanishes. Together with all its content.

My question is: is there some way, in the event that happens, that we can get some sort of backup of the great questions and/or answers that were posted during Poker.SE's life ? Personally, I'm proud of some of my answers. And there are many more that I find equally valuable.

Copy and pasting is a little too tedious for 2013. My initial thought was Data.StackExchange, but Poker.SE is not listed there.

So what do you think ? Is this doable if the sad day comes ?

PS: I believe the StackExchange license allows something like this, if no ownership of the material is claimed. However, I have very little experience with legal licenses, so I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event of a site being closed, the questions, answers and other content are archived in a data dump and made available to download for use under our Create Commons license. It is, essentially, a *backup* of the site (minus any personal information and other less useful content), so the content contributed by the participants would not be lost.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.